# Split String by comma separated , but not able to find generic solution

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, decode

```
String str = "\"{\"\"oman\"\"\",333,333,Locationoman,1,NULL,3.33333E+15,0,NULL,-1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,50036,1.42771E+12,0,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,0,1,3,0,1,T,F,F,0,Volume,-1,302,50036,50036,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,3,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,50036,0,1,0,OmanPrepaid,0,blrfts186_f861,CCC_USER_257,a082000000000033,\"16,436,113,650\",,NULL}";
```

I Have a String like this, but the output should be like

1. oman
2. 333
3. 333
4. Locationoman
5. 1
6. NULL
7. 3.33333E+15
8. 0
9. NULL
10. -1
11. NULL
12. NULL
13. NULL
14. NULL
15. NULL
16. NULL
17. NULL
18. NULL
19. NULL
20. NULL
21. NULL
22. NULL
23. 1
24. NULL
25. 50036
26. 1.42771E+12
27. 0
28. NULL
29. 0
30. NULL
31. NULL
32. NULL
33. NULL
34. NULL
35. NULL
36. NULL
37. NULL
38. 2
39. 0
40. 1
41. 3
42. 0
43. 1
44. T
45. F
46. F
47. 0
48. Volume
49. -1
50. 302
51. 50036
52. 50036
53. 0
54. 0
55. 0
56. 0
57. NULL
58. NULL
59. NULL
60. NULL
61. NULL
62. NULL
63. NULL
64. NULL
65. NULL
66. NULL
67. NULL
68. NULL
69. NULL
70. 3
71. NULL
72. NULL
73. NULL
74. 2
75. 1
76. 1
77. 1
78. 3
79. 1
80. 1
81. 1
82. 50036
83. 0
84. 1
85. 0
86. OmanPrepaid
87. 0
88. blrfts186_f861
89. CCC_USER_257
90. a082000000000033
91. 16,436,113,650
92. NULL
93. NULL

Check 91st value, all values which are in double quotes are at one index. Please help me .Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want `"16`, `436`..., `650"` or do you want the quotes excluded?

Comment: Your string starts with `\"{\"`, so there's a curly brace inside double quotes. Why it's excluded from the output? How it differs from `\"16,436,113,650\"`?

Comment: Ofcourse , these are the confusions I am also facing @Tagir Valeev.

Comment: Quotes should be excluded @npinti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex like so:

```
String[] tokens = str.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

Your string array now contains the items you want, with the 91st item not split because it is between quotes.

If you also want to remove quotes from the resulting elements you can do a for loop for all items:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace('\"', '');
}
```

Or for just one item:

```
tokens[90] = tokens[90].replace('\"', '');
```